# Mailchimp + Firebase - subscribe to newsletter

Tags: firebase, mailchimp, firebase-extensions

I am using Mailchimp and Firebase to send automated emails.

I have installed the extension and it using Firebase Console, but for Contact Status option I chose 'Pending'.

The thing is, I dont want every user that creates an account to be subscribed to the audiance, I want it to be 'Subscribed' just if he subscribes to the newsletter (it should happen on a click event on a button). I have also set up an automated email in Mailchimp (that is triggered immediately after subscribed contacts join your audience).

Do you know how can I achieve this? I don't have any written code yet, because I don't know where to begin with this.